# zf2 When I do addFeature(new Feature\SequenceFeature,...) for Postgres PDO, insert fails because columns and values are nulled out

Tags: postgresql, pdo, zend-framework2

I'm in Zend Framework 2, trying to get the last inserted id after inserting using postgresql PDO. The insert works fine unless I add a SequenceFeature, like this:

```
class LogTable extends AbstractTableGateway
{
    protected $table = 'log';

    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
    {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
        $this->featureSet = new Feature\FeatureSet();
        $this->featureSet->addFeature(new Feature\SequenceFeature('id','log_id_seq'));
        $this->resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
        $this->resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Log());
        print_r($this->getFeatureSet());

        $this->initialize();
    }
```

When I later do an insert like this:

```
            $this->insert($data);
```

It fails, because INSERT INTO "log" () VALUES (), so for some reason zf2 is nulling out the columns and values to insert, but only if I add that SequenceFeature.

If I don't add that feature, the insert works fine, but I can't get the last sequence value. Debugging the Zend/Db/Sql/Insert.php, I found that the values function is accessed twice with the SequenceFeature in there, but only once when it's not in there. For some reason when the SequenceFeature is there, all the insert columns and values are nulled out, possibly because of this double call? I haven't investigated further yet, but maybe it's updating the sequence and then losing the data when making the insert?

Is this a bug, or is there just something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Screw it! We'll do it live!

Definitely not the best solution, but this works. I just cut and pasted the appropriate code from Zend/Db/TableGateway/Feature/SequenceFeature.php and added it as a function to my LogTable class:

```
public function nextSequenceId()
{
    $sql = "SELECT NEXTVAL('log_id_seq')";
    $statement = $this->adapter->createStatement();
    $statement->prepare($sql);
    $result = $statement->execute();
    $sequence = $result->getResource()->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $sequence['nextval'];
}
```

Then I called it before my insert in my LogController class:

```
$data['id'] = $this->nextSequenceId();
$id = $this->insert($data);
```

Et voila! Hopefully someone else will explain to me how I'm really supposed to do it, but this will work just fine in the interim.